# Bootstrap Navbar toggledown not displaying links

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I am fairly new to bootstrap and I can't seem to figure out why, when resized to the size of a phone screen, the dropdown toggle that appears doesn't do anything.

Here is my code for the navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, name=viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

    <style>
        ul#menu li {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Finance Tracker</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href='#'>Navbar</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/allexpenses">All Expenses</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/allincomes">All Incomes</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/expenses">Add Expenses</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/incomes">Add Incomes</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/goal">Add Goal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am also utilizing flask and this is the base.html template although I don't believe that should affect the bootstrap.
Any help would be appreciated!

SOLVED:

Script tags for jquery, Popper.js and Bootstrap where outdated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the 3 final scripts, according to the bootstrap 4 [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), use these:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).